# issue with sql select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

i have the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT dr.Revision 
FROM tblActionHeader ah 
    INNER JOIN tblActionType at ON at.ActionTypeID = ah.ActionTypeID 
    INNER JOIN tblDocumentRevisionActionHeader drah ON drah.ActionHeaderID = ah.ActionHeaderID 
    INNER JOIN tblDocumentRevision dr on dr.DocumentRevisionID = drah.DocumentRevisionID 
    INNER JOIN tblDocumentHeader dh on dh.DocumentHeaderID = dr.DocumentHeaderID 
WHERE at.ActionTypeID=2 
UNION SELECT '(All)' 
      FROM tblActionHeader ah
```

it returns the following result set

```
-
(All)
0
0a
1
```

i need '(All)' to take at the top of the result set how can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways - first would be to put the "All" at the top of the UNION:

```
SELECT '(All)' AS revision
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT dr.Revision 
  FROM tblActionHeader ah 
  JOIN tblActionType at ON at.ActionTypeID = ah.ActionTypeID 
  JOIN tblDocumentRevisionActionHeader drah ON drah.ActionHeaderID = ah.ActionHeaderID   
  JOIN tblDocumentRevision dr ON dr.DocumentRevisionID = drah.DocumentRevisionID 
  JOIN tblDocumentHeader dh ON dh.DocumentHeaderID = dr.DocumentHeaderID 
 WHERE at.ActionTypeID = 2
```

The second is to assign an arbitrary value for ordering by:

```
SELECT x.revision
  FROM (SELECT '(All)' AS revision, 1 AS sort_order 
         UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT dr.Revision, 2 AS sort_order 
          FROM tblActionHeader ah 
          JOIN tblActionType at ON at.ActionTypeID = ah.ActionTypeID 
          JOIN tblDocumentRevisionActionHeader drah ON drah.ActionHeaderID = ah.ActionHeaderID   
          JOIN tblDocumentRevision dr ON dr.DocumentRevisionID = drah.DocumentRevisionID 
          JOIN tblDocumentHeader dh ON dh.DocumentHeaderID = dr.DocumentHeaderID 
         WHERE at.ActionTypeID = 2) x
ORDER BY x.sort_order, x.revision
```

I used the derived table approach in this example to make sure that only the `revision` column is in the final result set.

Use `UNION ALL` if you know the values will be distinct/unique -- `UNION` removes duplicates, and is slower for that reason.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
SELECT '(All)' from tblActionHeader ah
union all
select distinct dr.Revision from tblActionHeader ah inner join tblActionType at 
       on at.ActionTypeID = ah.ActionTypeID 
   inner join tblDocumentRevisionActionHeader drah 
   on drah.ActionHeaderID = ah.ActionHeaderID inner join tblDocumentRevision dr 
   on dr.DocumentRevisionID = drah.DocumentRevisionID inner join tblDocumentHeader dh 
   on dh.DocumentHeaderID = dr.DocumentHeaderID where at.ActionTypeID=2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Revision
FROM( 
    SELECT DISTINCT dr.Revision 
    FROM tblActionHeader ah 
        INNER JOIN tblActionType at ON at.ActionTypeID = ah.ActionTypeID 
        INNER JOIN tblDocumentRevisionActionHeader drah ON drah.ActionHeaderID = ah.ActionHeaderID 
        INNER JOIN tblDocumentRevision dr on dr.DocumentRevisionID = drah.DocumentRevisionID 
        INNER JOIN tblDocumentHeader dh on dh.DocumentHeaderID = dr.DocumentHeaderID 
    WHERE at.ActionTypeID=2 
    UNION SELECT '(All)' AS Revision
    ) tempT
ORDER BY Revision DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you looking for this ?

```
select top 1 as All from 
(
select distinct dr.Revision from tblActionHeader ah inner join tblActionType at 
on at.ActionTypeID = ah.ActionTypeID 
 inner join tblDocumentRevisionActionHeader drah 
 on drah.ActionHeaderID = ah.ActionHeaderID inner join tblDocumentRevision dr 
on dr.DocumentRevisionID = drah.DocumentRevisionID inner join tblDocumentHeader dh 
on dh.DocumentHeaderID = dr.DocumentHeaderID where at.ActionTypeID=2
)
```